# How can be add orWhere conditions in cakephp3.7 because in 3.7 orWhere deprecated

Tags: sql, cakephp, conditional-statements, cakephp-3.7

orWhere conditions in cakephp3.7 because in 3.7 orWhere deprecated

```
select * from Users where Users.state = 'UP' Or (Users.status =1 and Users.role=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `OR` keyword (and for better readability the optional `AND` keyword) with the nested array syntax:

```
$query->where([
    'OR' => [
        'Users.state' => 'UP',
        'AND' => [
            'Users.status' => 1,
            'Users.role' => 2
        ]
    ]
]);
```

or expressions:

```
$query->where(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $query
) {
    return $exp->or_([
        'Users.state' => 'UP',
        $query->newExpr()->and_([
            'Users.status' => 1,
            'Users.role' => 2
        ])
    ]);
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**